# Oracle-RAC and RAC Tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, retag-request

There are questions tagged Oracle-RAC and others tagged RAC.  They are both about Oracle Real Application Clusters, so it seems that one should be merged into the other and perhaps a synonym created.

Comment: If you have enough rep on questions with that tag, you can propose the synonym yourself [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/oracle-rac/synonyms). We'll then vote on it for you or the mods will directly approve it.

Comment: @NickChammas I don't have enough rep on the tag and I don't think anyone else does either.